# TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'mask')

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

i want to create LSTM network which can take two input as pad sequenced array as input and mask array  as masked input. I have written code as below:

```
def create_model():

#input 1 (pad sequence)
input_layer1 = Input(shape=(17640,1),name = 'input_layer')

#input 2 (mask)
input_layer2 = Input(shape=(17640,),name='input_mask')

#LSTM layer
LSTM_layer = LSTM(25,return_sequences=False,name = 'LSTM_layer',mask = input_layer2)(input_layer1)

#Dense layer
dense = Dense(50,activation='relu',kernel_initializer=he_normal(),kernel_regularizer=l2(0.0001),name = 'dense')(LSTM_layer)

#output layer
dense_1 = Dense(10, activation = 'softmax',name='dense_1')(dense)

#concat = concatenate([input_layer,input_mask])

model = Model([input_layer1],dense_1)

#compile
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001,decay = 1e-4),metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.AUC()])

return model
```

But I am getting error as:
TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'mask')
Looking into details of error it says that it has received unknown keyword argument. I also looking into similar type of error i.e keyword is different in those cases. Solution to those are specific to the problem. Could some one help me in resolving this error

Answer (score 3):

`mask` argument is not argument of a constructor, it's a call argument which should have dimension `[batch, timestamps]`. It's a call argument because mask can be different between runs. In other words, it should look like this:

```py
LSTM_layer = LSTM(25, return_sequences=False, name = 'LSTM_layer')(input_layer1, mask = input_layer2)
```

Comment: Thanks Proko, Earlier i was trying giving both call arguments separately. then i tried it giving it inside LSTM parameter taking reference from tensorflow documentation. But this solution works. Thanks again